# Using heckman in combination with mi estimate (Stata)

Tags: stata, multiple-imputation, heckman

This is a Stata specific question, and may be better directed to Stata's own Statalist, but I'm trying here first.

Here is the situation. I have a multiply-imputed data set, where the number of imputations = 10 and where imputations are only performed on independent variables. I would like to run the `heckman` command on these data, using the `mi estimate` prefix. The `heckman` command is not a "supported command", but it is possible to force estimation using the `cmdok` option. My questions are these: Why isn't `heckman` a supported command? Are the results that I get when I force Stata to fit the model (using the `cmdok` option) valid? Or, is there some statistical reason why a Heckman-style selection procedure should not be used in a multiply-imputed data setting?

Comment: If cross-posting, please do pay attention to http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/resources/statalist-faq/#crossposting

Comment: Will do. I haven't posted this question to the Statalist (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Barry, I don't think there are any issues. MI is more traditionally used in medical and other social sciences than in economics, where the tradition is to make as few model assumptions as possible as possible, so as to make inference as robust to potential violations of these assumptions. So economists don't use it as much, as Stata did not invest much time testing how `mi` works with `heckman`.

As a technical matter, there are transformed coefficients that `heckman` reports as rho, the correlation between the residuals in the two regressions. They are parameterized and internally estimated with an [arctanh transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation), so `mi estimate` will report the transformed correlation, which you would need to translate back if you need to using an appropriate `nlcom`.

Comment: Fisher transformation is atanh, nor arctan.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the `mi` command yet but I am using the user-written command `mim` in Stata for multiple imputed dataset. There are basically two issues in regard to your question. First, Rubin's method can be still used for the regression coefficients in the Heckman model as being used for linear regression. Second, marginal effects can be still combined as per Rubin's method as is mentioned [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-03/msg01021.html). As to why one need to invoke `cmdok`, Yulia Marchenko  provides the following reasons (details [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-08/msg00479.html) in Statalist)

Commands are officially supported by `mi estimate` if they

1) produce the numerical results that `mi estimate` needs and stores them 
        where `mi estimate` expects (explained below)

2) work properly with available `mi estimate` postestimation tools, and

3)  produce good-looking `mi estimate` output.